# LaTeX Error: Can be used only in preamble even though all packages are defined in preamble

Tags: texshop

Many similar errors I found on this platform, but my problem is bit different.
There is main.tex file which including two files from expternal sources and it contains no `\documentclass{article}`. But, Latex is giving me error and not giving the proper output.

```
.\chapters/abstract_v1.tex:1: LaTeX Error: Can be used only in preamble.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation. 
Type H ≤return> for immediate help.
l.3 \begin{document}
?
```

following are lines which I am including in my `main.tex` file:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {images/} }
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[a4paper, width=150mm, top=25mm, bottom=25mm, bindingoffset=6mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{ragged2e}


\makeatletter
\newcommand\NoWarnNat{
\xpatchcmd{\NAT@citexnum}{\PackageWarning}{\let\PackageWarning\@gobbletwo\PackageWarning}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\NAT@citex}{\PackageWarning}{\let\PackageWarning\@gobbletwo\PackageWarning}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\nocite}{\PackageWarning}{\let\PackageWarning\@gobbletwo\PackageWarning}{}{}
}
\makeatother


\NoWarnNat

%\author{Python Buddha}
\date{02 March 2020}

\begin{document}

\input{titlepage}

\pagenumbering{roman}

\chapter*{Dedication}


\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Dedication}

\chapter*{Declaration}

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Declaration}

\cleardoublepage
\tableofcontents

\listoffigures


\cleardoublepage


\chapter*{Abstract}
\input{chapters/abstract_v3}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Abstract}

\chapter*{Foreword}
\input{chapters/abstract_v1}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Foreword}

\chapter*{Introduction}
\input{chapters/introduction_v2}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Introduction}

\cleardoublepage

\pagenumbering{arabic}

\chapter{Add Language identifier to highlight code}
\input{chapters/chapter1_v1}

\chapter{Put Returns between paragraphs}
\input{chapters/chapter2_v1}

\chapter{For Linebreak add 2 spaces at end}
\input{chapters/chapter3_v1}

\chapter{Indent code by 4 spaces}
\input{chapters/chapter4_v1}

\chapter{To make Links}
\input{chapters/chapter5_v1}

\chapter*{Formatting Help}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Formatting Help}
```

other files look like this:

`abstract_v2.tex`

````
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.\\


`abstract_v1.tex`

```\chapter*{Foreword}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.\\
````

Comment: There seems to be an `\end{document}` missing. Can you produce a proper minimal non-working example (maybe just two files, `main.tex` and one that gets included via `\input`)

Comment: your input `chapters/abstract_v1` has some code which should be placed before `\begin{document}` in the preamble that is why the error in compiling--you can cut out the offensive code and manually place it in the preamble rather than make it a part of the `chapter/abstract_v1`

Comment: We need to see the included documents. As others have mentioned it seems you have preambles in the included files. This is normally not permitted. But if you in your master doc (your MWE) add a package like `docmute` then the reamble of any included document is simply ignored. `docmute` is just on of several packages that others this feature.

Comment: The error message you show has an internal incongruence: the first line (`.\chapters/abstract_v1.tex:1: LaTeX Error: Can be used only in preamble.`) says that the error is at line 1 of the file `abstract_v1.tex`, but the fourth (nonblank) line says that the error occurs at line 3.  Are you sure that you did copypaste the error message from the console?  Anyway, it looks like the file you input (that is, `abstract_v1.tex`) contains a line (either the first or the third) that reads `\begin{document}`: such a line does not normally belong there.

Comment: @GuM thank you for your support. There was incongruence in my file. I removed preambles in included files and it solved the problem. Now facing different issue, only few pages are able to appear in newly generated PDF.